# How to compute 2 different nodesets (siblings) in XPath from the same parent?

Tags: python, xpath

How do I use the and operator '|' to compute 2 node sets? In other words, compute data of 2 siblings with different tag names. In this case : I want data from both edition and edition2 tags. I tried '| and it didn't work.

**XML :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<wikimedia>
  <projects>
    <project name="Wikipedia" launch="2001-01-05">
      <editions>
        <edition language="English">en.wikipedia.org</edition>
        <edition language="German">de.wikipedia.org</edition>
        <edition language="French">fr.wikipedia.org</edition>
        <edition language="Polish">pl.wikipedia.org</edition>
        <edition language="Spanish">es.wikipedia.org</edition>
        <edition2 language="Spanglish">egs.wikipedia.org</edition2>
        <img src="hello.gif">hello</img>
      </editions>
    </project>
    <project name="Wiktionary" launch="2002-12-12">
      <editions>
        <edition language="English">en.wiktionary.org</edition>
        <edition language="French">fr.wiktionary.org</edition>
        <edition language="Vietnamese">vi.wiktionary.org</edition>
        <edition language="Turkish">tr.wiktionary.org</edition>
        <edition language="Spanish">es.wiktionary.org</edition>
        <edition2 language="Spanglish">egs.wiktionary.org</edition2>
        <img src="hello.gif">hello</img>
      </editions>
    </project>
  </projects>
</wikimedia>
```

**Python :**

```
>>> wikixml.xpath('//edition/text() | edition2/text()')
['en.wikipedia.org', 'de.wikipedia.org', 'fr.wikipedia.org', 'pl.wikipedia.org', 'es.wikipedia.org', 'en.wiktionary.org', 'fr.wiktionary.org', 'vi.wiktionary.org', 'tr.wiktionary.org', 'es.wiktionary.org']
```

### EDIT

I got it working after the answer but I also want to select the value of `img/@src`
I managed to do this using the union operator `|`

```
>>> wikixml.xpath('//edition/text() | //edition2/text() | //img/@src')
['en.wikipedia.org', 'de.wikipedia.org', 'fr.wikipedia.org', 'pl.wikipedia.org', 'es.wikipedia.org', 'egs.wikipedia.org', 'hello.gif', 'en.wiktionary.org', 'fr.wiktionary.org', 'vi.wiktionary.org', 'tr.wiktionary.org', 'es.wiktionary.org', 'egs.wiktionary.org', 'hello.gif']
```

How to do this using a single predicate and the `self` notation like it's done here with two elements

```
/wikimedia/projects/project/editions/ *[self::edition or self::edition2]/text()
```

now that we have `@src` and `text()`?

Comment: Have you tried `'//edition/text() | //edition2/text()'` or `'//edition/text() or edition2/text()'` or `'//edition/text() or //edition2/text()'`?

Comment: @SimeonVisser that comment could have been an answer. It's certainly one way to do this. Not very efficient but functionally correct. Anyway, +1 you go.

Comment: By the way, what does "pipe" mean in this context?

Comment: I was referring to '|' as pipe.

Comment: @ThinkCode: `|` is the standard *union* operator in XPath -- not "pipe". It accepts nodesets as its left and right arguments and produces the set union of the two node-sets. Using `|` it is possible to select the wanted nodes all with one XPath expression -- such expression is provided in my answer to this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use

```
wikixml.xpath('//edition/text() | //edition2/text()')
```

or more efficiently

```
wikixml.xpath('//*[self::edition or self::edition2]/text()]
```

or even better

```
wikixml.xpath('/wikimedia/projects/project/editions/*[self::edition or self::edition2]/text()]
```

### As for the question update

> I also want img's @src too. How to do this with the self notation now
>   that we have @src and text()?

Honestly, I don't know if there's a way to select from both the element and attribute axes at the same time using the above notation. I doubt it.

You can either do it with a single XPath, but giving up the self::notation (at least for the attribute):

```
/wikimedia/projects/project/editions/ *[self::edition or self::edition2]
|
/wikimedia/projects/project/editions/img/@src
```

or select `edition`, `edition2` and all elements containing an `src` attribute

```
/wikimedia/projects/project/editions/ *[self::edition or self::edition2 or attribute::src]
```

and then process the result to fetch the value of `src`

That's about as much as you can do in **XPath 1.0**
As per Dimitre Novatchev's suggestion, **XPath 2.0** allows you to write it this way:

```
/wikimedia/projects/project/editions/(*[self::edition or self::edition2] | img/@src )
```

Comment: In another example, if there is an <img src="hello.gif">Hello</img> after the edition2 tag and we also want img/@src - how would we write it? Since text() applies to edition(2) while @src applies to img. Thank you so much!

Comment: Do you want it to be selected with a single expression along with these two nodes? Please update the question with another example of input and output.

Comment: The last expression doesn't select the `src` attribute -- it selects any element that has a `src` attribute. @ThinkCode wants to have the `src` attributes themselves to be selected -- and this is possible to specify in a single XPAth expression.

Comment: @DmitreNovatchev I never claimed it would. Read my answer (the post-update part) carefully. First, I suggested a single XPath to select both the elements and the attribute, much the way you just answered. The second listing shows a way to select "edition, edition2 and all *elements containing* an src attribute". Such result set can be searched again for just the elements or just the src. The OP asked if these three nodes could be selected using a simple XPath (without union) with a predicate. I say it can't. But I'd be more than happy to find out there is a way after all.

Comment: I believe there doesn't exist a way to wikixml.xpath('/wikimedia/projects/project/editions/*[self::edition/text() or self::edition2/text() or self::img/@src]]. I will stick to this : for editionstag in wikixml.xpath('/wikimedia/projects/project/editions'): editionstag.xpath('editon2/text() or img/@src) ... Thanks Tom and Dimitre for your solutions.

Comment: @Tom: But there actually exist such expressions -- one is in my answer.

Comment: @ThinkCode: Such single XPath expressions actually exist -- one is in my answer.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev what we mean is that it's not possible to select these three nodes (edition, edition2 and src) without using a union **|** and using just a single predicate **[ ... ]** for all three at once.

Comment: @Tom: Why "without using a union"? ThinkCode is asking exactly the opposite: "How do I use the and operator '|' to compute 2 node sets?" This means you are not answering the question that is asked.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev the question has been edited after a comment exchange between me and ThinkCode. It was originally about two nodes, hence the first part of my answer. In the last listing for the original questions, I removed the union operator. ThinkCode asked if it could be done the same way to fetch an attribute as well. I asked them to edit the question but it's a bit unclear. Also, the first listing in the edited-in part of my answer is exactly the same as yours (apart from the fact that you're using * and that I specify edition and edition2, while you fetch everything apart from img)

Comment: @Tom: I see now -- I hadn't noticed your first expression -- it is partly greyed out and not well-formatted by the SO code formatter. Also, the OP's update isn't clear -- particularly what he means by "the self notation"

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev I edited the answer and I think the OP won't mind if I edit the question as well.

Comment: @Tom: In the meantime I added to my answer a single XPath 2.0 expression that doesn't walk twice to `editions.

Answer (score 2):

**Use**:

```
   /*/*/project/editions/*[not(self::img)]
|
   /*/*/project/editions/img/@src
```

**or in XPath 2.0 use**:

```
/*/*/project/editions
               /(*[not(self::img)] | img/@src)
```

Comment: Neat. I didn't know it was possible to put it in parentheses like this. Shame it's XPath 2.0 only

Comment: @Tom: Yes, XPath 2.0 is very powerful, indeed.

Comment: XPath 2.0 enabled in Python 2.6.x? (I should Google it before I ask but I mean to say that XPath 2.0 is not default across older Python versions)

Comment: @ThinkCode: To the best of my knowledge (and I absolutely don't know Python) the answer is negative.